How to make metadata immutable TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
I have followed this tutorial.
It works fine but I have 2 questions.
How to make metadata immutable?
  // Instruction to initialize Metadata Account data
  const initializeMetadataIx = createInitializeInstruction({
    programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
    metadata: mintAddress, // Account address that holds the metadata
    updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
    mint: mintAddress, // Mint Account address
    mintAuthority: updateAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
    name: metaData.name,
    symbol: metaData.symbol,
    uri: metaData.uri,
  });

updateAuthority does not accept null.
Other question is that I want to update metadata with another request, if they are mutable but I cannot find the Instruction to do that.
@solana/spl-token-metadata package there is not tutorial on that

Use the tokenMetadataUpdateAuthority helper and set newAuthority to null.
https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/functions/tokenMetadataUpdateAuthority.html
It invokes this instruction on the token extensions program:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program-2022/src/extension/token_metadata/processor.rs#L166

tokenMetadataUpdateAuthority
need to be signed, with private key, I need the instruction so the wallet -addon can sign it from the  client

I need this    createUpdateAuthorityInstruction({
programId,
metadata: mint,
oldAuthority: updateAuthorityPublicKey,
newAuthority,
})

use createUpdateAuthorityInstruction from @solana/spl-token-metadata, which is what tokenMetadataUpdateAuthority does under the hood.
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/js/src/extensions/tokenMetadata/actions.ts#L373

Can you please tell me how to update the metadata? I need to change the Name and the symbol and the uri, how to do that?

createUpdateFieldInstruction https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/js/src/instruction.ts#L84

isnt this only for additional custom fields and not name symbol uri?

name, symbol, uri are required fields of the metadata: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/js/src/instruction.ts#L44-L46

this worked for making it immutable
createUpdateAuthorityInstruction({ programId, metadata: mint, oldAuthority: updateAuthorityPublicKey, newAuthority, }) 


export const getUpdateMetadataFieldIx = async ({
  mintAddress,
  updateAuthority,
  field,
  value,
}: {
  mintAddress: PublicKey;
  updateAuthority: PublicKey;
  field: "name" | "symbol" | "uri";
  value: string;
  isImmutable?: boolean;
}) => {
  const updateFieldIx = createUpdateFieldInstruction({
    programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    metadata: mintAddress,
    updateAuthority: updateAuthority,
    field, // Key of the field to update
    value, // Value of the field to update
  });

  return updateFieldIx;
};

this is for updating metadata
